# iOS 12 DatePicker value changed issue

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, uidatepicker, ios12

There is a date picker which is the @IBOutlet. It is an input view of my text field

myTextField.inputView = picker

The problem is that when I scroll datepicker - it scrolls okay but value in the text field is not changing. The text field is still empty not matter how much times I try to change it.

The biggest problem is that this issue reproduces rarely "in a wild" and seems like only on iOS 12. Only several users of my app reproducing this issue always when all other can't see it even when they are trying to.
May it be an iOS12 issue with the date picker?? Maybe someone know what it could be??

This issue is displayed in the the videos below

Comment: We cant find a problem in your code without seeing it

Comment: I know this, but the code was not touched but the issue start to show up when iOS 12 released(

Answer (score 0):

You have to catch the dateChanged event of the picker and set the textField by yourself the way you want, an exemple:

```html
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

// Call this in the init to setup the dateFormatter
func setupDateFormatter() {
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
}

// Here you catch the dateChanged event and you set the textField text
func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {
    dateTextField.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
}
```

Comment: yup, it is already implemented and working well. but there is 3 users that always getting issue with not updated value when all other users and tester can't get this issue even when they try to